# addEventListener() and removeEventListener() in loop with passing argument

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML `table` and two button `update` and `cancel`.

**I want these operations to be performed:**

- If `update` button is clicked then all the cells will turn to be clickable and if a certain cell is clicked its background color will be green.
- If `cancel` button is clicked then no cells will be clickable now.

**What Result I Get**

Only last cell is updated. No matter which cell I click.

**What I tried so far...**

- HTML Table

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th scope="col">SUN</th>
            <td class="bg-danger" scope="col" id="SUN8"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="SUN9"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="SUN10"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="SUN11"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="SUN12"></td>
            <td class="bg-warning" rowspan="6"><br>B<br>R<br>E<br>A<br>K</td>
            <td scope="col" id="SUN2"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="SUN3"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="SUN4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th scope="col">MON</th>
            <td scope="col" id="MON8"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="MON9"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="MON10"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="MON11"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="MON12"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="MON2"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="MON3"></td>
            <td scope="col" id="MON4"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

- The two buttons

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="updateSchedule" style="display: block;"
        onclick="startUpdate()">
        Update
</button>

<button class="btn btn-secondary mt-3" href="" id="cancelUpdate" style="display: none;"
        onclick="cancelUpdate()">
        Cancel
</button>
```

- Button reference in JavaScript

```
update = document.getElementById("updateSchedule")
cancel = document.getElementById("cancelUpdate")
```

- I have a list of all cell ids

```
const id_list = ["SUN8", "SUN9", "SUN10", "SUN11", "SUN12", "SUN2", "SUN3", "SUN4", "MON8", "MON9", "MON10", "MON11", "MON12", "MON2", "MON3", "MON4"]
```

- **JavaScript Funtions**

```
    function startUpdate() {
        update.style.display = "none"
        cancel.style.display = "inline-block"
        let cell;
        for (let i = 0; i < id_list.length; i++) {
            cell = document.getElementById(id_list[i])
            cell.style.cursor = "pointer"
            cell.addEventListener("click", showAlert.bind(cell));
        }
    }

    showAlert = function () {
        cell.classList.add("bg-success");
    }

    function cancelUpdate() {
        update.style.display = "block"
        cancel.style.display = "none"

        for (let i = 0; i < id_list.length; i++) {
            cell = document.getElementById(id_list[i])
            cell.style.cursor = "default"
            cell.removeEventListener("click", showAlert);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide us the `table` HTML? It might be an issue with the way you're associating the IDs.

Comment: All you need is `this` or the `.target` property of the `Event` argument: [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: `.removeEventListener()` expects the exact same function that was bound with `.addEventListener()`. `Function.prototype.bind()` returns a new `function` -> `.removeEventListener()` + `.bind()` need some extra work.

Comment: `cell` is undefined in `showAlert` or `cancelUpdate`...

Comment: Where is `cell` defined that is used inside `showAlert`?

Comment: @mdeamf I have edited the post

Comment: @DaniilAndreyevichBaunov cell is passed  as argument

Comment: _"cell is passed as argument"_ - No, it isn't. `showAlert()` expects no arguments, and `.bind(cell)` does not magically pass `cell` as argument. And even if it would do that, as `showAlert()` has no named parameters you would not be able to access it via `cell` _in_ `showAlert()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update = document.getElementById("updateSchedule");
cancel = document.getElementById("cancelUpdate");

const id_list = ["SUN8", "SUN9", "SUN10", "SUN11", "SUN12", "SUN2", 
                 "SUN3", "SUN4", "MON8", "MON9", "MON10", "MON11", 
                 "MON12", "MON2", "MON3", "MON4"]

function startUpdate() {
    update.style.display = "none"
    cancel.style.display = "inline-block"
    let cell;
    for (let i = 0; i < id_list.length; i++) {
        cell = document.getElementById(id_list[i])
        cell.style.cursor = "pointer"
        cell.addEventListener("click", showAlert);
    }
}

showAlert = function (event) {
    event.target.classList.add("bg-success");
}

function cancelUpdate() {
    update.style.display = "block"
    cancel.style.display = "none"
    for (let i = 0; i < id_list.length; i++) {
        cell = document.getElementById(id_list[i])
        cell.style.cursor = "default"
        cell.removeEventListener("click",showAlert)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfectly working. Thanks for saving my time.. So the "cell" reference is not needed to be passed with bind() ? It is the target, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code inside your `.addEventListener` function like below:

I have updated the code for `startUpdate`, you can make the same changes for your `cancelUpdate` function :)

**Javascript**:

```
function startUpdate() {
        update.style.display = "none"
        cancel.style.display = "inline-block"
        let cell;
        for (let i = 0; i < id_list.length; i++) {
            cell = document.getElementById(id_list[i])
            cell.style.cursor = "pointer"
            cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
           });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this will work for addEventListener() but then the removeEventListener() won't work..

Comment: Is your goal to change the background colored cell after  clicking  on cancel button ?

Comment: No, cancel button won't reset the change that I made. It just make the cells unclickable. But the colors that I made after clicking update button will be stored in the UI